# how to store random numbers in an array one by one and after appending evaluate the array

Tags: javascript

```js
var player1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

const score = [];

const scorelength = 6;

function generate() {

  if (score.length < scorelength) {
    score.push(player1)
    console.log(score);

  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a question and code that demonstrates what you've tried. Preferably without major syntax errors, and with example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare player 1 score outside of the function you will end up with the same score 6 times

```
const scorelength = 6;

function generate() {
var player1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if (score.length < scorelength) {
    score.push(player1)
  }
  console.log(score);
}

generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but if you need to do something with your array each time a number is pushed inside, you can use a recustive function as follow :

```
<div id="app">
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
</div>

<script>
    var myArray = [];

  function generate() {
    if(myArray.length <= 10){
      myArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
      console.log('Do something, array = ', myArray);
      generate();
    }
  }
</script>
```